# How can I compute a duration from two dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have this query, that's been giving me some issues, it looks like this:

```
UPDATE servicecontracts 
   SET planned_duration = (to_char(due_date) - to_char(start_date) + 1)
      ,actual_duration =''
      ,progress = NULL 
 WHERE servicecontractsid = '263'
```

After some research, I managed to figure out what this query is trying to do, it' s just trying to find the planned duration, by subtracting the due date and the start date. Why, this is trying to do that by subtracting strings, I do not know. Also, the `to_char` function requires a second parameter.

So, anyway, now I need to find the `planned_duration`, but how do I do that. According to the Postgresql docs, the `to_char` function doesn't have an option to return an integer, if you set it to return text and  then if you try to convert the string into an integer using explicit casts, like `::integer`, you get an error because an integer can't have colons in there.
So, is there a way for `to_char` to return an integer that somehow represents the date, and then subtract the two? 
If not, what should I do to carry this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtracting two `date` types from each other should return their difference in days.

```
SET planned_duration = (due_date - start_date)
```

Not sure why `to_char` is being used, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: But you can't cast an interval to int like that. See my post / the manual.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Would you mind explaining why? I just tested `select ('2011-10-04'::date - '2011-08-04'::date)::int` which correctly returned `61`

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work both with the casting and without, I wonder if it's because the field is character varying. Or, maybe it just doesn't matter.

Comment: @zermy - Yeah, the cast to `int` is probably unnecessary. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It works if the type of the fields is `date`. It doesn't with `timestamp`. I was assuming timestamp, but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Ah, that makes sense. It was reasonable to think that actually.

Answer (score 2):

I quote from the fine manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40.12-08');
```

Result: 982384720.12

But for computing intervals, there is simpler way:

```
SELECT (due_date - start_date)
```